# grails generate-views - Script 'GenerateViews' not found

Tags: grails

I have upgraded to grails version 2.3.6, and now when I try to run generate-views from the command line:

```
 grails generate-views
```

I get the error:

```
 Script 'GenerateViews' not found, did you mean:
 1) IntegrateWith
 2) CreateService
 3) CreateIntegrationTest
 4) CreateFilters
 5) Interactive
 Please make a selection or enter Q to quit:
```

I have also tried this with the optional domain class argument, but it results in the same error.

However, other grails commands such as

```
grails run-app
```

work just fine.

I am using a macbook running OSX 10.9.2, java 1.7.0._25-b15.
Has anyone else had this problem?
thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue that resolved after running "grails refresh-dependencies"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2.3 release of Grails moved scaffolding to a plugin. See the [release notes](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html) about upgrading for other details.

Add this to your BuildConfig:

```
plugins {
  compile ':scaffolding:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was missing the compile scaffolding:1.0.0 plugin. Now it builds my “LogFile” views part way, generates an edit.gsp and _form.gsp, then fails

    Error executing script GenerateViews: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
    No signature of method: static org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping() 
    is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass) values: [Artefact > LogFile]

Comment: Sounds like something isn't quite right in your domain class LogFile. Post the domain class?

Comment: I kept making little changes to my LogFile domain class, and I set the DataSource to create, and ran grails clean and run-app. When the app was running OK, I went back to trying the generate-views, and the error went away. I'm not sure specifically what was broken, but you were right, there was something with the domain class that generate-views did not like. Thanks, -John

Comment: No worries. Glad you got it all sorted out.